# Difference between (func)() and (func).call(window)

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

I am studying how to create some plugins using `angularjs` and in some of them I have faced this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    //code...
}).call(window);
```

what is the difference from just using a self-invoking function like that below?

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    //code...
})();
```

Comment: The first looks like it's from someone who desperately wants `this`'s default value to refer to `window` despite being in strict mode. Seems like an awful idea to me.

Comment: @JLRishe I made a `console.log(this)` inside each example and get what you said now. The first one logs the `window` object while the second logs `undefined`. So it is better to just use window inside my body function if I need it, right?

Comment: Yes, I would say that's typically preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two invocations will have different `this` values.

This code

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    console.log(this)
})();
```

will log `undefined` because direct non-method invocations of strict-mode functions use a `this` value of `undefined`.

This code

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    console.log(this)
}).call(window);
```

will log `window` since the first argument to `call` is used to supply `this` to the function being invoked.

If I had to guess, I'd say this is being done to mimic the non-strict behavior of using `window` (instead of `undefined`) for `this` of a bare non-method invocation. Simply use `window` if you mean `window`.

Comment: That's very clarifying. I get it now. That means if I remove `'use strict'` from my self-invoking function I would get the same result as using `call(window)`?